# Excel cut a string between two characters

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I would like to cut out all a specific strong from 4000+ rows in Excel - but preserve a value from the string that I cut out.

The original:
([#partname](http://www.productlink.com/part/partname) )

Which I would like to be the following:

## partname

These links/hyperlinks/codes are not in all the cells, but in some of the cells its present more than once. And in others not present at all.

I´m using Excel 2007.

I have however also tested in Excel 2010 - and tried to use the automatic tool to wipe out hyperlinks - it didn't work.

HERE ONE OF THE CELL-INFO (From cell A1):

```
    <h2>PPC-308 Bright indictor</h2>
    <h3>Original part for PPC</h3> <h3>This part fits all these models:</h3>
    Model 1<br />
    Model 2<br />
    Model 3<br />
    Model 4<br />
    Model 5<br />
    Model 6<br />
    <p>PPC Bright Indicator will give you instant information as to your vehicles status. Once installed, simply turn your CSM battery on and the indicator will show you the power level of your battery. The SDF level indicator should only be used with hump back battery packs. 
Adding the PPC <strong>Battery Pack</strong> (<a href= "http://www.partlink.com/part/2012">#2012</a> ) to your Machine increases stability performance and time.<strong> TXX </strong>(<a href= "http://www.partlink.com/en/part/87022">#87022</a>) is recommended to support the battery.</p> 
    <p>The Battery Level Indicator is designed for battery packs such as the <a href= "http://www.partlink.com/en/part/A222">#A222</a> Hump Installer Pack. Kit includes: 
    <ul> <li>IDICATOR</li> 
    <li>MAGASINE</li> <li>COVER PLATE</li></ul>
```

Comment: sorry I missed a few characters in the front:

The original:
(<a href="http://www.productlink.com/part/partname">#partname</a> )

Which I would like to be the following:
#partname

Does that solve the question?
Its a hyperlink when shown in HTML.
Those Hyperlinks are not in all the cells (4000+). But in some of the cells its present more than once. And in others not present at all.

Comment: What have you done so far to get to the solution of your problem?

Comment: I have tried Excel 2010 as it should have an option to remove it. But that would not leave the value within the string be.

I simply do not know how to remove a string - but still keep a value from within the string.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will need to be adjusted depending on the formatting with multiple hyperlinks. With one or none, this is fine.

I would insert two columns to the right of column with the hyperlink.

In the first column, I would insert a function =Right(**Insert cell reference A1**,13).

In the second column, I would insert the following functions =IF(**Insert cell reference A1**=**Insert your hyperlink text**,Left(**Insert cell reference B1**,9),"partname")

I would then copy and paste special values over the original and delete the two columns.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. The "partname" and the http-link/hyperlink varies from cell to cell so unfortunately not a fixed value. Its a bit more tricky :)

Comment: That's fine, simply include in the first column =Right(**Insert cell reference A1**,len(**insert cell reference A1**)-find(#partname,**Insert Cell reference A1**,1))

Comment: I do not understand it...or it simply doesnt work here. I will update the original post with the actual cell-info - hopefully you can perhaps give an example on what you mean?